# emacs org-mode: Number of working days between two timestamps

Tags: emacs, timestamp, spreadsheet, org-mode

The following table in Emacs' org-mode automatically calculated the number of days between timestamps in columns 1 and 2 and put the results in column 3.

```
| <2015-07-24 Fri> | <2015-07-22 Wed> | 2 |
#+TBLFM: $3=$1-$2
```

I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the number of *working* days in the range given by columns 1 and 2, i.e. excluding weekends.

Comment: That would require setting up a custom set of holidays to define what constitutes "working days".  So as not to reinvent the wheel entirely, you may be interested in building upon work that I have already done in a different thread that counts business days (based upon a user-defined calendar) and incorporate that into your custom tailored table solution.  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7118/2287  The project will require some intermediate `elisp` to modify it to your specific needs. `Calc` also has something built in that utilizes the generic holiday schedule that you may be interested in.

Comment: Another function the original poster may be interested in taking a look at is `calendar-count-days-region`:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Counting-Days.html  That function can also be modified to help write the solution to this custom table issue.

Comment: Maybe `calc` can help you? You can define what is a holiday there, see [the manual here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Business-Days.html).